# hyphen in ALTER SCHEMA sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I keep getting error for the following query

```
ALTER SCHEMA dbo TRANSFER domain-USERS\user.tablename;
```

I tried other table of the same database with a different name and it works fine. (like username.tablename)

So I think the problem is the hyphen in the username.

I also tried the following query but no help.

```
ALTER SCHEMA dbo TRANSFER 'domain-USERS\user'.tablename;

ALTER SCHEMA dbo TRANSFER 'domain-USERS\user.tablename';
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the correct syntax to transfer the table [A] from schema [B] into the schema [C].

```
ALTER SCHEMA C TRANSFER [B].[A]
```

On the right side of `TRANSFER`, there shouldn't be a WINDOWS login name.

Comment: Unless of course a schema was created with the user's name, as an sp_adduser does.